# How to shorten this part of the code (tkinter in python)

Tags: python, tkinter

I am writing the code for the game Tic Tac Toe using Python and the tkinter library. Code length: 240 lines, but the problem is that there is a function that checks who won..There's a lot of if and elif statement. And I would like to cut it. At the end of each victory, there is a function (turn off the buttons) and a function (restart the game). It is necessary to reduce the part with if and elif.

```
def victory_check():
    global winner
    winner = False

    # Is the user with X the winner?
    if button_1["text"] == "X" and button_2["text"] == "X" and button_3["text"] == "X":
        button_1.config(bg='#EE2923')
        button_2.config(bg='#EE2923')
        button_3.config(bg='#EE2923')
        winner = True
        tk.messagebox.showinfo('Tic Tac Toe', 'User playing for X - won!')
        buttons_off()
        restart()
        
    elif button_4["text"] == "X" and button_5["text"] == "X" and button_6["text"] == "X":
        button_4.config(bg='#EE2923')
        button_5.config(bg='#EE2923')
        button_6.config(bg='#EE2923')
        winner = True
        tk.messagebox.showinfo('Tic Tac Toe', 'User playing for X - won!')
        buttons_off()
        restart()

    elif button_7["text"] == "X" and button_8["text"] == "X" and button_9["text"] == "X":
        button_7.config(bg='#EE2923')
        button_8.config(bg='#EE2923')
        button_9.config(bg='#EE2923')
        winner = True
        tk.messagebox.showinfo('Tic Tac Toe', 'User playing for X - won!')
        buttons_off()
        restart()
        
    elif button_1["text"] == "X" and button_4["text"] == "X" and button_7["text"] == "X":
        button_1.config(bg='#EE2923')
        button_4.config(bg='#EE2923')
        button_7.config(bg='#EE2923')
        winner = True
        tk.messagebox.showinfo('Tic Tac Toe', 'User playing for X - won!')
        buttons_off()
        restart()

    elif button_2["text"] == "X" and button_5["text"] == "X" and button_8["text"] == "X":
        button_2.config(bg='#EE2923')
        button_5.config(bg='#EE2923')
        button_8.config(bg='#EE2923')
        winner = True
        tk.messagebox.showinfo('Tic Tac Toe', 'User playing for X - won!')
        buttons_off()
        restart()

    elif button_3["text"] == "X" and button_6["text"] == "X" and button_9["text"] == "X":
        button_1.config(bg='#EE2923')
        button_4.config(bg='#EE2923')
        button_7.config(bg='#EE2923')
        winner = True
        tk.messagebox.showinfo('Tic Tac Toe', 'User playing for X - won!')
        buttons_off()
        restart()

    elif button_1["text"] == "X" and button_5["text"] == "X" and button_9["text"] == "X":
        button_1.config(bg='#EE2923')
        button_5.config(bg='#EE2923')
        button_9.config(bg='#EE2923')
        winner = True
        tk.messagebox.showinfo('Tic Tac Toe', 'User playing for X - won!')
        buttons_off()
        restart()

    elif button_3["text"] == "X" and button_5["text"] == "X" and button_7["text"] == "X":
        button_3.config(bg='#EE2923')
        button_5.config(bg='#EE2923')
        button_7.config(bg='#EE2923')
        winner = True
        tk.messagebox.showinfo('Tic Tac Toe', 'User playing for X - won!')
        buttons_off()
        restart()

    # Is the user with O the winner?
    elif button_1["text"] == "O" and button_2["text"] == "O" and button_3["text"] == "O":
        button_1.config(bg='#EE2923')
        button_2.config(bg='#EE2923')
        button_3.config(bg='#EE2923')
        winner = True
        tk.messagebox.showinfo('Tic Tac Toe', 'User playing for O - won!')
        buttons_off()
        restart()
        
    elif button_4["text"] == "O" and button_5["text"] == "O" and button_6["text"] == "O":
        button_4.config(bg='#EE2923')
        button_5.config(bg='#EE2923')
        button_6.config(bg='#EE2923')
        winner = True
        tk.messagebox.showinfo('Tic Tac Toe', 'User playing for O - won!')
        buttons_off()
        restart()

    elif button_7["text"] == "O" and button_8["text"] == "O" and button_9["text"] == "O":
        button_7.config(bg='#EE2923')
        button_8.config(bg='#EE2923')
        button_9.config(bg='#EE2923')
        winner = True
        tk.messagebox.showinfo('Tic Tac Toe', 'User playing for O - won!')
        buttons_off()
        restart()

    elif button_1["text"] == "O" and button_4["text"] == "O" and button_7["text"] == "O":
        button_1.config(bg='#EE2923')
        button_4.config(bg='#EE2923')
        button_7.config(bg='#EE2923')
        winner = True
        tk.messagebox.showinfo('Tic Tac Toe', 'User playing for O - won!')
        buttons_off()
        restart()
        
    elif button_2["text"] == "O" and button_5["text"] == "O" and button_8["text"] == "O":
        button_2.config(bg='#EE2923')
        button_5.config(bg='#EE2923')
        button_8.config(bg='#EE2923')
        winner = True
        tk.messagebox.showinfo('Tic Tac Toe', 'User playing for O - won!')
        buttons_off()
        restart()

    elif button_3["text"] == "O" and button_6["text"] == "O" and button_9["text"] == "O":
        button_1.config(bg='#EE2923')
        button_4.config(bg='#EE2923')
        button_7.config(bg='#EE2923')
        winner = True
        tk.messagebox.showinfo('Tic Tac Toe', 'User playing for O - won!')
        buttons_off()
        restart()

    elif button_1["text"] == "O" and button_5["text"] == "O" and button_9["text"] == "O":
        button_1.config(bg='#EE2923')
        button_5.config(bg='#EE2923')
        button_9.config(bg='#EE2923')
        winner = True
        tk.messagebox.showinfo('Tic Tac Toe', 'User playing for O - won!')
        buttons_off()
        restart()

    elif button_3["text"] == "O" and button_5["text"] == "O" and button_7["text"] == "O":
        button_3.config(bg='#EE2923')
        button_5.config(bg='#EE2923')
        button_7.config(bg='#EE2923')
        winner = True
        tk.messagebox.showinfo('Tic Tac Toe', 'User playing for O - won!')
        buttons_off()
        restart()

    if count == 9 and winner == False:
        tk.messagebox.showinfo('Tic Tac Toe', 'There is no winner - a tie')
        restart()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is to half the amount. First you'll check the condition for player X then for O.

```
for player in ['X','O']:
    if button_1["text"] == player  and button_2["text"] == player  and button_3["text"] == player :
        button_1.config(bg='#EE2923')
        button_2.config(bg='#EE2923')
        button_3.config(bg='#EE2923')
        winner = True
        tk.messagebox.showinfo('Tic Tac Toe', 'User playing for '+player+' - won!')
        buttons_off()
        restart()
```

You can also put the different winning combination-checks in the for-loop. And then combine with or-keywords.

```
for player in ['X','O']:
    condition1 = button_1["text"] == player  and button_2["text"] == player  and button_3["text"] == player
    condition2 = ...
    if condition1 or condition2 or condition3:
        button_1.config(bg='#EE2923')
        button_2.config(bg='#EE2923')
        button_3.config(bg='#EE2923')
        winner = True
        tk.messagebox.showinfo('Tic Tac Toe', 'User playing for '+player+' - won!')
        buttons_off()
        restart()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use *smart data* instead of code.

Put your buttons in a `list` or `tuple`.
Then you'd have `buttons[0]` up to and including `buttons[8]`.

Next you should have a nested tuple of winning combinations.

```
winners = (
   (0,1,2),
   (3,4,5),
   (6,7,8),
   ...
)
```

And you could replaces all of your code with a nested loop:

```
for comb in winners:
    for player in ('X', 'O'):
        if all(buttons[j]["text"] == player for j in comb):
            winner = True
            for k in comb:
                buttons[k].config(bg='#EE2923')
            tk.messagebox.showinfo('Tic Tac Toe', f'User playing for "{player}" - won!')
            buttons_off()
            restart()
```